# Is "meant for " correct english?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What is wrong with this sentence

> "This equipment is meant for connecting devices."

Is the phrase *"meant for"* correct English?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your sentence.

Comment: Yes, "meant for" means that its purpose is to connect devices.

Answer (score 3):

***[Meant for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meant%20for%20(someone))*** is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> (informal)    perfectly suited for
>
> - *You were meant for me and I was meant for you. I'm not surprised that they have such a happy marriage. I always knew that they were meant for each other*.

(M-W)

You are using it correctly in your sentence.

Comment: But it can also have a literal meaning, i.e. the designer of the equipment meant it to be used for connecting devices. 'Intended for' would be an alternative.